Groupby with condition - best practice
I want to a groupby with a condition and then feed back the result to the original dataframe. In this case feature 'COl_COND' could either be 1 or 0, and the feature to be summarized is 'AMOUNT'.
Below this is done by performing two groupby's, storing the result in pandas series and then merge back to the original dataframe.
Can this be done without doing a merge?
If memory usage is an issue, what method would be the most rational to apply?
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,6],
            'COL_COND':[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0],
            'AMOUNT':[5, 80,100, 50, 100, 100, 20, 1, 51, 11, 12]})

series1 = df[df.COL_COND==1].groupby('ID')['AMOUNT'].sum().rename('sum_amount_1')
series0 = df[df.COL_COND==0].groupby('ID')['AMOUNT'].sum().rename('sum_amount_0')

df = df.merge(series1.to_frame().reset_index(), on='ID', how='left')\
.merge(series0.to_frame().reset_index(), on='ID', how='left')

print(df)

    ID  COL_COND  AMOUNT  sum_amount_1  sum_amount_0
0    1         1       5     5.0000000            80
1    1         0      80     5.0000000            80
2    2         1     100   100.0000000            50
3    2         0      50   100.0000000            50
4    3         1     100   120.0000000           100
5    3         0     100   120.0000000           100
6    3         1      20   120.0000000           100
7    4         0       1           NaN             1
8    5         1      51    51.0000000            11
9    5         0      11    51.0000000            11
10   6         0      12           NaN            12


I think a merge is actually a good approach, but doing it only once for all columns :)

Use DataFrame.assign for create helper columns, so possbile use only one groupby with GroupBy.transform, if need missing values for not existing categories use lambda function with sum and min_count=1:
out = df.join(df.assign(sum_amount_1 = df['AMOUNT'].where(df['COL_COND'].eq(1)),
                        sum_amount_0 = df['AMOUNT'].where(df['COL_COND'].eq(0)))
                .groupby('ID')[['sum_amount_1','sum_amount_0']]
                .transform(lambda x: x.sum(min_count=1)))
print(out)
    ID  COL_COND  AMOUNT  sum_amount_1  sum_amount_0
0    1         1       5           5.0          80.0
1    1         0      80           5.0          80.0
2    2         1     100         100.0          50.0
3    2         0      50         100.0          50.0
4    3         1     100         120.0         100.0
5    3         0     100         120.0         100.0
6    3         1      20         120.0         100.0
7    4         0       1           NaN           1.0
8    5         1      51          51.0          11.0
9    5         0      11          51.0          11.0
10   6         0      12           NaN          12.0


A generic approach (independent of the number of conditions) could be to aggregate with pivot_table, then merge (after renaming with add_prefix):
out = df.merge(df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='COL_COND',
                              values='AMOUNT', aggfunc='sum')
                 .add_prefix('sum_amount_'),
               left_on='ID', right_index=True
               )

Output:
    ID  COL_COND  AMOUNT  sum_amount_0  sum_amount_1
0    1         1       5          80.0           5.0
1    1         0      80          80.0           5.0
2    2         1     100          50.0         100.0
3    2         0      50          50.0         100.0
4    3         1     100         100.0         120.0
5    3         0     100         100.0         120.0
6    3         1      20         100.0         120.0
7    4         0       1           1.0           NaN
8    5         1      51          11.0          51.0
9    5         0      11          11.0          51.0
10   6         0      12          12.0           NaN

Intermediate pivot:
COL_COND  sum_amount_0  sum_amount_1
ID                                  
1                 80.0           5.0
2                 50.0         100.0
3                100.0         120.0
4                  1.0           NaN
5                 11.0          51.0
6                 12.0           NaN


jezrael's method is the Best. I believe, the method using pivot_table is the least efficient method for huge datasets.
Method 1 :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6],
    'COL_COND': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'AMOUNT': [5, 80, 100, 50, 100, 100, 20, 1, 51, 11, 12]
})

for cond in [0,1]:
    condfilter = (df['COL_COND'] == cond)
    sums = df.loc[condfilter].groupby('ID')['AMOUNT'].sum()
    print('sums :')
    print(sums)
    df[f'sum_amount_{cond}'] = sums.reindex(df['ID']).fillna(0).values
print(df)
"""
    ID  COL_COND  AMOUNT  sum_amount_0  sum_amount_1
0    1         1       5            80           5.0
1    1         0      80            80           5.0
2    2         1     100            50         100.0
3    2         0      50            50         100.0
4    3         1     100           100         120.0
5    3         0     100           100         120.0
6    3         1      20           100         120.0
7    4         0       1             1           0.0
8    5         1      51            11          51.0
9    5         0      11            11          51.0
10   6         0      12            12           0.0
"""

Method 2 :
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6],
                   'COL_COND': [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                   'AMOUNT': [5, 80, 100, 50, 100, 100, 20, 1, 51, 11, 12]})

df_cond_1 = df[df['COL_COND'] == 1].groupby('ID')['AMOUNT'].sum()
df_cond_0 = df[df['COL_COND'] == 0].groupby('ID')['AMOUNT'].sum()

df['sum_amount_1'] = df['ID'].map(df_cond_1)
df['sum_amount_0'] = df['ID'].map(df_cond_0)

print(df)
"""
   ID  COL_COND  AMOUNT  sum_amount_1  sum_amount_0
0    1         1       5           5.0            80
1    1         0      80           5.0            80
2    2         1     100         100.0            50
3    2         0      50         100.0            50
4    3         1     100         120.0           100
5    3         0     100         120.0           100
6    3         1      20         120.0           100
7    4         0       1           NaN             1
8    5         1      51          51.0            11
9    5         0      11          51.0            11
10   6         0      12           NaN            12
"""

